# Homomorphism to abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

Let $\phi :G \rightarrow G'$ be group homomorphism and $H$ is subgroup of $G$ such that $ker(\phi)\subseteq H$. Also $G'$ is abelian. Then which of the following are correct.

- H is normal in G
- $ker(\phi)=H$
- H is not normal in G

I know all subgroups of G' is normal in G' and  pre image of  normal subgroup is normal in G.
Will this imply H normal in G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. $\phi(H)$ is a subgroup of $G'$. All subgroups of an abelian group are normal. Therefore the preimage of $\phi(H)$ is normal in $G$.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $H$ is normal in $G$ is a direct consequence of the [correspondence theorem of groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem_(group_theory)).

Actually, since $H$ contains $\ker\phi$ and $f(H)$ is normal in $G’$(Since G’ is abelian), apply the theorem we have $H$ is normal in $G$.